# docusignapi - How can I get the filed "sentDateTime" from the signers?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using REST API (docusign). I need to get the field "sentDateTime" from the signers.

I use this Request:

/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

The REST API never returns the field "sentDateTime" from the signers.

How can I get this field from the signers?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share why you need to check "sentDateTime" from the signers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this field from the signers/recipients. Instead, you will get the field from the envelope they are included in. See below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this field is the global "sentDateTime" for the envelope. My envelope has three signers. I would like to know this field each of them.

In the documentation of the signers the field "sentDateTime" appears  for each one of them.

Comment: I don't see any "sendDateTime" in the recipient [REST API documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#signers-recipient). Which documentation are you looking at ?
There are some *DateTime properties but as you can see, they are reserved for DocuSign.
Also, it seems to me that the sentDateTime would be identical for all the recipients, hence why DocuSign put the property at the envelope level

Answer (score 0):

Currently API does not return "sentDateTime" for each signer, once Signer completes the signing ceremony then you can see two fields, "signedDateTime" and "deliveredDateTime" in the API response. I would propose to use DocuSign Connect for getting these values as it saves you from polling, In DS Connect, DocuSign sends below data for each recipient

```
<RecipientStatus>
        <Type>Signer</Type>
        <Email>signerEmail@gmail.com</Email>
        <UserName>Signer1</UserName>
        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
        <Sent>2017-11-22T11:22:36.833</Sent>
        <Delivered>2017-11-22T11:26:10.607</Delivered>
        <Signed>2017-11-22T11:26:20.483</Signed>
```